# How many ways can 100 people sit in an auditorium given certain constraint

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

[image: Image of question]

An auditorium has 2 rows of seats in each row . 100 distinguishable people sit in the seats one at a time , Subject to the condition that  each person , except for the first person to sit in each row , must sit immediate to the left or rigth of an occupied seat ,and no 2 people can sit in the same seat . In how many ways can this process occur .
Answer 2^98×C(100,50)

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Starting with a smaller set of seats/people might be a good idea.

Comment: should add;  I'm not sure the rules are complete.  I gather the first person can just at random from the $100$ seats?  But who is the first to sit in the new row?  Is it always the $51^{st}$ person or can anyone decide to be the first?

Comment: Anyone can decide to be first

Comment: Well, if anyone can decide to go first, your answer looks too low.  Say the first person sits in the middle of row $1$ and the second person decides to sit in the middle of row $2$.  Then thereafter each person will generally have $4$ choices of where to sit.  Your proposed answer seems consistent with just having the $51^{st}$ person be the first to move to the new row.

Answer (score 1):

I will be assuming that the people are indistinguishable even though the "in" is crossed out in the photo. The people will be distinguished by the order in which they sit down.

**Step 1**

Enumerate all the people from $1$ to $100$. They will sit down in this order.

We can choose who among them sit in the first row in ${100 \choose 50}$ ways.

**Step 2**

You may assume that number $1$ to $50$ are sitting in the front row.

They decide to form a queue first before sitting down.

Person $1$ starts forming the queue.

Person $2$ can either go immediately in front of person $1$, or immediately behind person $1$.

Person $3$ can then either go immediately in front of person $1$ and $2$, or immediately behind them, and so on.

Person $n$ can either go immediately in front of person $1$, $2$, ..., $n-1$, or immediately behind them.

Finally, person $50$ also chooses where to go, and they have now, in total, made $49$ binary choices when forming this queue. So they end up with one of $2^{49}$ possible ways of forming a queue.

The other $50$ people repeat the process of forming a (separate) queue, something which can also be done in $2^{49}$ ways.

**Step 3**

Now, magically, everyone realizes that they each had a seat underneat them the entire time.

This gives a total of ${100 \choose 50} \cdot 2^{49} \cdot 2^{49}$ ways of sitting down.

Comment: I would like to clarify that according to the question person 3 can only go infront of person 2 or behind person 1

Comment: If you take people as indistinguishable, $100$ identical balls (say) can be divided into two heaps of $50$ in only one way

Comment: The people are indistinguishable up until the point at which we decide their order, i.e. enumerate them. If they were distinguishable, and then we would decide their order, we would have to multiply our answer by a factor of $100!$

Comment: If you first divide them into two groups of $50$, mulriplying by $100!$ will overcount the arrangements.

Comment: The number $100!$ refers to the number of different orders they can sit down in. This is decided before we decide which row they sit in.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lulu that the question is vaguely worded.
However, I believe the key lies in the last sentence," In how many ways can this **process** occur." In other words, after dividing the people into two groups of $50$ each in $\binom{100}{50}$ ways, in how many orders can the seats numbered $1-50$ in each row be taken, observing the adjacency clause.

For the second part, taking one row of $50$, it is obvious that the last seat taken must either be #$1$ or #$50$. Now let us reverse the process, imagining all $50$ people seated, and **take out** people one by one. The first out would be #$1$ or #$50$, and supposing you took out #$1$,the next out would be #$2$ or #$50$, and so on, (*ie always taking out from either extreme*)  except that the last person out would have only choice, thus a row can be filled in $2^{49}$ ways.

Thus for $2$ rows and $100$ seats, the answer will be $\dbinom{100}{50}2^{98}$

### PS:

As already remarked, there is ambiguity regarding the question. I have taken an interpretation that leads to the given answer.

However, if we are to not only consider the order in which  rows are filled, but also who fills which row and seat, the answer will be $\dbinom{100}{50}\times2^{98}\times{(50!)}^2$

Comment: If A and B are sitting down in rows 1 and 2, then this process could happen in these $4$ ways: i) First A sits in row 1 then B sits in row 2,  ii) First A sits in row 2 then B sits in row 1, iii) First B sits in row 1 then A sits in row 2 iv) First B sits in row 2, then A sits in row 1. The number of processes is thus ${2 \choose 1} \times 2^0 \times 2!$, and not ${2 \choose 1} \times 2^0 \times 1!^2$.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests such a meaning. Anyway, this is not part of the main question, so let us not debate on it.